# Make each ListView Row the width and height of the ListView Container?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to create a horizontal `ListView` where each row is the width and height of the `ListView` container, it gives the impression of a paged look and feel with 1 row showing on the screen.

The problem is I am unsure how to style the rows so they match the width and height of the `ListView`. Any ideas?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ListView,
  TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native'


import Spinner from 'react-native-loading-spinner-overlay';


var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});


export default class ParcelView extends Component {


  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Parcel Screen',
  };


  constructor() {
    super();

    this.renderRow = this.renderRow.bind(this);
    this.pressRow = this.pressRow.bind(this);
    this.fetchData = this.fetchData.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([]),
      loadingVisible: false
    };
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }


  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View>
        <Spinner visible={this.state.loadingVisible} textContent={"Loading..."} textStyle={{color: '#FFF'}} />
        <View style={styles.listWrapper} >
            <ListView
                dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                renderRow={this.renderRow}
                horizontal={true}
                style={styles.listView}
            />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }


   renderRow( rowData ){
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.pressRow()}>
        <View>
          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>{rowData.userId}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }


  pressRow( rowID: number ){

    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

    var text = "Testing";

    // Navigate To Parcel Screen
    navigate('Parcel', { name: 'Jane' });

  }


  fetchData(){

    this.setState({loadingVisible: true});

    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", {method: "GET"})
     .then((response) => response.json())
     .then((responseData) =>
     {
        this.setState({ dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(responseData)});
     })
     .done(() => {
        this.setState({loadingVisible: false});
     });

  }


}


var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  listWrapper: {
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#F6F6F6',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "#000",
    height: 300,
    margin: 10
  },
  row: {
    backgroundColor: '#ccc',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "#000",
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
  },
  listView: {
    backgroundColor: '#ccc',
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ParcelView component could set an `onLayout` prop for the ListView. When `onLayout` is called, you can save the ListView's width and height into state. Then, when it comes time to renderRow, the ParcelView can set `width` and `height` for the rows it renders.
Also make sure to set `pagingEnabled` to true on the ListView, so that you can let the native ScrollView handle the swipe gestures.